# How do I define class methods outside it in typescript reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-big-calendar

I want to use methods for the class as following:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
render() {
let { date } = this.props
let range = MyComponent.title(date)

return <TimeGrid {...this.props} range={range} eventOffset={15} />
}
}
```

My method is:

```
MyComponent.title = date => {
return `My awesome week: ${date.toLocaleDateString()}`;
};
```

But I am getting error :

> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'typeof MyComponent'

Comment: `MyComponent.title(date)` => `this.title(date)`

Comment: I've tried the code you wrote, I do not have any error, please check:
https://codesandbox.io/s/1qkz1ko073?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You component will look like this.Add static to your method title.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
      static title=date => {
          return `My awesome week: ${date.toLocaleDateString()}`;
       };
      render() {
          let { date } = this.props
          let range = MyComponent.title(date)
          return <TimeGrid {...this.props} range={range} eventOffset={15} />
      }
}
```